# Sitecore 8.1 Rich Text Editor Image error

Tags: sitecore, sitecore8, sitecore8.1

I'm developing a Sitecore 8.1 Initial Release site and have run into an issue with the Rich Text Editor and images.

When a user adds an image to the editor, everything works fine. However, if the user checks the Properties of the image in the editor, clears the Properties dialog, and accepts the RTE's changes, the image disappears and a browser error occurs saying the image cannot be found. This also happens if the Image Map Editor is opened.

Looking at the markup generated, the working src value is "-/media/.ashx". After looking at the properties, the src value is changed to "-/media/.ashx&h=230&w=375".

Any idea where this "&h=230&w=375" is coming from and how to stop or correct it?

Comment: Seems like a bug, I would raise it with Sitecore, The parameters should be  `?h=230&w=375`

Comment: Relooking at my post, I didn't realized some parts of the url were taken out. But you're right that it looks like a bug. I'll talk with Sitecore. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I contacted Sitecore Support. What I found was a bug in 8.1 initial release which has been fixed in later versions. I was given an updated file to replace some Rich Text Editor javascript and that fixed it for me.

We're already committed to this release of Sitecore for now. For others, I'd probably recommend updating Sitecore to a later release.